# Como hacer para que visual studio 2022 no cierre mi consola de depuración en un proyecto MAKE

Tags: c++, makefile, visual-studio-2022, make

he creado un proyecto de C++ en visual studio 2022 usando la plantilla "Proyecto de archivos MAKE", coloque el nombre y le di a crear, me pregunto sobre los comandos de compilación coloque make, make clean, make, y cree el respectivo Makefile todo se compila correcto pero cuando le doy a F5 para depurar, la consola donde esta la salida del programa se cierra y no puedo ver los resultados, no quiero tener que añadir PAUSE ni ningún loop o instrucción que no permita al depurador llegar a `return 0` en el final de programa.